# What image handling application is used in the movie Devlin?

Tags: untagged

In the movie [Devlin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104097/) I see at minute 30 those scenes

[image]

[image]

The "/usr4" directory tell me that OS is [Irix](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX)

Does anyone recognize the application?

Comment: Are there any other stills of the computer setup as well as other screens? So far it looks rather like multiple image viewer windows.

Comment: I would strongly suspect it was just knocked up for the film.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like an X11 application. And I agree with @AlanB that it looks knocked up to me.

Comment: */usr4/* isn't directly an Irix-unique thing. It was common to a lot of SV Unixes (including PC Unixes). Irix used a heavily souped-up Motif, which this screenshot doesn't really resemble.

Comment: What is the logo (and writing) along the bottom of the monitor? Is that a made up brand for the film?

Comment: I don't know the logo, I don't think is a brand for the movie, they usually use real hardware

Comment: logo looks suspiciously like Silicon Graphics logo, except it isn't!